SwiftUI TapGesture and DragGesture conflict
I have both .onTapGesture and .gesture(DragGesture()) modifiers on my view item and I animate it with .offset() modifier. The problem is when I drag my item it stays in it's place until I drag it for certain distance. This creates choppy animation for me. I think that's because SwiftUI thinks i'm using tap gesture, but in this case I don't need tap gesture active, until some state bool variable is true. So it works like switch between drag and tap modes.
struct Block: View {
    @State private var offsetX: CGFloat = 0
    @Binding var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        ItemView
          .offset(x: offsetX)
          .onTapGesture {
              if isActive {
                    //do actions
              }
          }
          .gesture(
              DragGesture()
                  .onChanged { value in
                      if !isActive {
                          offsetX = value.translation.width
                      }
                  }
                  .onEnded { _ in
                      if !isActive {
                          offsetX = 0
                      }
                  }        
          )
        }
    }
}

I tried deleting .onTapGesture and animation works perfectly without chopping, but I need both gestures.

You could try using .simultaneousGesture or/and  DragGesture(minimumDistance: ...)

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks! Using bold .simultaneousGesture solves this problem
